# 301 Redirect Root Domain to Subdirectory of Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my urls from **www.example.com/images/** to **static.example.com/img/**

```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/images/$ [NC]
> #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://static.example.com/img/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But i got too many 500 Internal Server Errors. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only match host name using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable.

You need to use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ http://static.example.com/img/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: My mistake, I omitted a space before `[NC]`.

Comment: what is NC mean exactly ?

Comment: `NC` stands for `No Case` which is used for ignore case comparison.